# how to insert images using Texworks?

Tags: graphics

I'm using TexWorks to compile a math article and want to add some PNG images in between.

As is said on [LaTeX/Importing Graphics -- Including graphics](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Importing_Graphics#Including_graphics)

1. I've included the graphicx package
2. and at the place where I want the image to be, I've used `\includegraphics{myimage}`
   The image file and `.tex` file, both are on the desktop.

The error shown is:

```
! LaTeX Error: File `myimage' not found.
```

I'm a complete novice in TeX. So, please explain in detail but in simple terms.

Comment: Hi, welcome to TeX.sx! Have a look at http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Importing_Graphics. If you're still stuck after reading that article, please edit your question to include more details (it's much too general at the moment).

Comment: Ah, sorry, you can't include GIFs, they need to be either PNG or JPG (see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34774/including-gif-image-in-pdflatex-document). You'll have to convert them first.

Comment: I've tried to include a PNG also. Edited.

Comment: Is the file called `myimage.png`? And are you sure both files are in the same directory, and you're calling `pdflatex` from the same directory?

Comment: oh, I got it now. Also, how do I include multiple images in a row?

Comment: By calling `\includegraphics` for each file. Please don't ask follow-up questions in comments, but edit your original question or open a new one. Also, you need to show some research effort and make your question more precise. It's not at all clear what you mean by "multiple images in a row". Do you want to include all images in a certain directory? Or a number of images in a sequence (like `image1.png`, `image2.png`...)? Or three completely separate images?