# Unable to have a gif-picture with transparent background in the title of Beamer Poster

Tags: beamer, beamerposter, posters

I am trying to follow this [discussion](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/109389/how-can-i-make-the-title-of-my-beamerposter-appear-on-the-same-page-as-the-actua), but I get the following error when I am trying to have a picture in the title.

**My TeX**

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[orientation=portrait, size=a0]{beamerposter} 
\mode<presentation>{%
    \usetheme{Frankfurt}%
}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\title
{
\includegraphics[height=4cm]{logo.gif}
} 

\setbeamersize{text margin left=0cm,text margin right=0cm} %removes left and right margins 

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[t]{}
\begin{beamercolorbox}{}
\maketitle
\end{beamercolorbox}
\vskip 50mm
  \begin{block}{Title}
    Hello world
  \end{block}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

I get the errors like this

```
Package hyperref Warning: Token not allowed in a PDF string (Unicode):
(hyperref)                removing `\@ifnextchar' on input line 22.
```

similar error message as [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10555/hyperref-warning-token-not-allowed-in-a-pdf-string).
I get an empty sheet after running the code.

**How can you have a picture in the title of Beamer class for a poster?**

Comment: Your code works fine on my machine (with TeXWorks + MikTeX 2.9), after replacing `logo.gif` with `image` from the `mwe` package.

Comment: I removed the package **mwe**, and still the same problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**pdflatex does not support the gif format!** See the [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34774/including-gif-image-in-pdflatex-document) (<- link to answer) from [Martin Scharrer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/2975/martin-scharrer). "Just" create a valid png with transparency and include it.

You can test the transparency for example by including it in a PowerPoint document.

Answer in a nutshell (`pdftex` manual, possible image types):

> The image type is specified by the extension of the given file name: .png stands for png image, .jpg (or
>   .jpeg) for jpeg, .jbig2 (preferred, but .jb2 works also) for jbig2, and .pdf for pdf file.

Comment: You link to Martin, but you do not include the link to his answer. **Can you update the link where you refer?** There are many ways to create the transparency. OSX Preview and magic wand create very sharp corners. I have not been able create a good transparency with Photoshop CC. I have white background in the picture.

Comment: Hello. The link to the answer is the "answer". Maybe you didn't see it. But I can update my answer anyway and add the actual answer.

Comment: I accept this answer because it answers the question. My next problem is to have such a transparency which I accepts for my picture, probably created by Photoshop CC.

Answer (score 3):

use

```
\title{\texorpdfstring{\includegraphics[height=4cm]{logo}}{}}
```

an image cannot be part of the bookmarks. And, of course, use a `.png`, `.pdf` or `.jpg` image format.

Comment: of course...didn't see that it's part of the bookmark